# Laravel Docker Nginx not loading static (public) files

Tags: laravel, docker, nginx

I am using docker to run my laravel project, I have an app (php) and nginx container.

Locally everything is working but once I setup docker on my AWS EC2 server and pulled my ECR docker containers to the EC2 server no static content is loading.

I have ran `php artisan route:list` and all the web.php routes are there and seem to be working, when I go to my domain the page loads with no styling since all the static files in the public directory return 404 errors.

This is the configuration of my nginx container

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name {domain};
    root /var/www/html/public;

    index index.php index.html;

    charset utf-8;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    error_page 404 /index.php;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass subscription_manager_php:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /var/www/html/public$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    }

    location ~ /\.(?!well-known).* {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

On the EC2 server I am then running nginx which is proxying into this container and this is my configuration

```
server {
    server_name {domain};

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8003;
        proxy_set_header Host            $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
    }

    listen 80;
}
```

The nginx server is running on port :8003 BTW incase this is asked.

I thought this location block on the container

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
}
```

would just load what ever url is passed such as `{domain}/images/test.png` and if that doesnt exist then it would look at `index.php` to see if a route exists.

**UPDATE**

These are the commands I am running to pull and run the ECR containers

```
aws ecr get-login-password --region eu-west-2 | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin {ecr-path}
docker pull {ecr-path}/subscription.manager/php:latest
docker pull {ecr-path}/subscription.manager/nginx:latest
docker rm -f subscription_manager_php || true
docker rm -f subscription_manager_nginx || true
docker network inspect subscription_manager_network >/dev/null 2>&1 || docker network create subscription_manager_network
docker run -d --network="subscription_manager_network" --name="subscription_manager_php" -v /home/ubuntu/.env.subscription_manager:/var/www/html/.env -v subscription_manager_php_storage:/var/www/html/storage/ {ecr-path}/subscription.manager/php:latest
docker run -d -p 8003:80 --network="subscription_manager_network" --name="subscription_manager_nginx" {ecr-path}/subscription.manager/nginx:latest
docker exec subscription_manager_php php artisan migrate --force
```

Comment: Your understanding of that location block is correct. Looks like nginx search static files in a wrong directory. Re-check, is `/var/www/html/public/images/test.png` really a right file path?

Comment: @IvanShatsky Thank you for clarifying, I thought I was going crazy! I just checked and the path is 100% correct, that is where the files are stored on the nginx docker container. Everything works fine locally but for some reason it breaks on my EC2 server...

Comment: Do I need to do anything with my nginx conf on the EC2 server or does that also look fine?

Comment: Are you using docker-compose with different containers for nginx and php? Does nginx have access via its local filesystem to that `public` directory? You probably should share a volume between two containers?

Comment: @IvanShatsky that might be the case, I have added the commands I am running to pull and run the ECR images on my EC2 server. Do you think I need a volume for the public directory, could you show me an example if you know what I can change to fix it please

Comment: Sorry I meant I added the commands to my question

Comment: Yes, I think you need a separate volume for your public directory and you need to make it accessible to both containers. Unfortunately docker isn't my strong side and I can't give you an example how to do it. Check docker volumes [documentation page](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/). If your PHP app being executed. and only static files cannot be served, looks like only a php container has access to that folder right now...

Comment: @IvanShatsky Thanks for the help I will try my best to find the solution. It would make sense that is the issue since it works locally and I am sharing the root volume on that in my docker-compose.yml

Answer (score 1):

If you use docker-compose add folowing line in you configuration for nginx container:

```
volumes_from:
   - {name-of-your-php-container}
```

So let say you php container has name "php-blog". So ngnix config should looks like:

```
  nginx-far:
    build: nginx
    ports:
      - '8000:80'
    links:
      - php-blog
    volumes_from:
      - php-blog
    volumes:
      - ./logs/nginx/:/var/log/nginx
```